# android DatePickerDialog year 2037

Tags: android, android-widget

If i use DatePicker i can set the min and max year.

```
<DatePicker android:startYear="1900"
              android:endYear="3000"
...
```

How can i set the endYear for the DatePickerDialog?

My attempt with a style did NOT work:

```
<resources>
    <style name="datePickerStyle" arent="@android:style/Theme_Dialog_Alert">
        <item name="android:endYear">3000</item>
        <item name="android:startYear">1000</item>
   </style>
</resources>

new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.datePickerStyle, ...
```

The DatePickerDialog getDatePicker() method does not exist in app versions < 11.

Is there any way to do this?